# List of all the Universities/Colleges in USA

Tags: research-process

I am looking for list of all the universities/colleges in the USA. I read somewhere that there are around 6000 universities/colleges in US. Also, I want a list of the engineering colleges in the USA

Comment: Not sure this is relevant for this site. Also, surely there are at least some (broad) criteria that you can use to narrow down a search?

Comment: This list wouldn't be very practical. Listing Harvard alongside local community colleges like NVCC really doesn't benefit anyone.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_engineering_schools#United_States

Answer (score 3):

At  http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation you can download a list of all accredited US colleges, universities, and similar educational programs. I counted 9746 unique institutions.

Answer (score 1):

The typical place for students to start looking, despite its flaws, is the [US News university rankings](http://www.usnews.com/rankings).  This lists something on the order of 2000 educational institutions, including all of the higher-ranked institutions, both overall and in many categories such as engineering.